# could not retrieve json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to get json data but I am not able to do so. I am trying to get weather data for a specific city. Here is my json data

```
{ 
"data": 
{ 
    "current_condition": 
    [ 
        {
            "cloudcover": "100", 
            "humidity": "100", 
            "observation_time": "01:07 PM", 
            "precipMM": "0.2", 
            "pressure": "993", 
            "temp_C": "-6", 
            "temp_F": "21", 
            "visibility": "10", 
            "weatherCode": "368",  
            "weatherDesc": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "Light snow showers" 
                } 
            ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0027_light_snow_showers_night.png" 
                } 
            ], 
            "winddir16Point": "N", 
            "winddirDegree": "360", 
            "windspeedKmph": "9", 
            "windspeedMiles": "6"
        } 
    ],  
    "request": 
    [ 
        {
            "query": "Tampere, Finland", 
            "type": "City" 
        } 
    ],  
    "weather": 
    [ 
        {
            "date": "2012-01-07", 
            "precipMM": "2.3", 
            "tempMaxC": "-4", 
            "tempMaxF": "25", 
            "tempMinC": "-8", 
            "tempMinF": "17", 
            "weatherCode": "326",  
            "weatherDesc": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "Light snow" 
                } 
            ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0011_light_snow_showers.png" 
                } 
            ], 
            "winddir16Point": "NNW", 
            "winddirDegree": "336", 
            "winddirection": "NNW", 
            "windspeedKmph": "9", 
            "windspeedMiles": "5" 
        }, 
        {
            "date": 
            "2012-01-08", 
            "precipMM": "0.0", 
            "tempMaxC": "-7", 
            "tempMaxF": "19", 
            "tempMinC": "-9", 
            "tempMinF": "17", 
            "weatherCode": "116",  
            "weatherDesc": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "Partly Cloudy" 
                } 
            ],  
            "weatherIconUrl": 
            [ 
                {
                    "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" 
                } 
            ], 
            "winddir16Point": "SSE", 
            "winddirDegree": "148", 
            "winddirection": "SSE", 
            "windspeedKmph": "5", 
            "windspeedMiles": "3" 
        } 
    ] 
}
}
```

and here is how I am trying to get it using jquery

```
var container = $('.weatherContainer');
        var url = 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Tampere&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=a84523bbed133415120701&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function(w) {
            //console.log(w.data);
            var contents = "<div class='c'>";
            $.each(w.data, function(i, res){
                //alert('h');
                $.each(res.weather, function(j,action) {
                    //alert('i');
                    contents += "<section>" + action.tempMaxC + "</section>";
                });
            });
            contents += "</div>";
            container.append(contents);
        });
```

Help please. How can I achieve it? Above code doesnt work for me.

Here what the error is

```
object is undefined
length = object.length,                                   jquery-latest.js (line 630)
```

I want to get the data inside the weather object. How can I get that?

Ok here is the image of output when I uncomment console.log [enter link description here](http://i40.tinypic.com/2vlqvqd.png)

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem analysis. It's not even a problem description.

Comment: What actually happens when you run the code? Do you get an error in the console? I notice you've got a commented out `console.log(w.data)` - what does that print if you uncomment it?

Comment: ok it gives this error object is undefined
[Break On This Error] length = object.length,

Comment: when I uncomment console.log(w.data). it shows this Object { current_condition=[1], request=[1], weather=[2]}

Comment: I edited my post, I added the error. The error is something I do not understand. Help please

Comment: I am trying to get data inside the weather object. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is your nested "each" loops. You are telling jQuery for each object in the response's `data` object, find each `weather` object inside of those and iterate over it. There is only one `weather` object and it's directly inside of `data`, so remove the outer loop and simplify with this single loop:

```
$.each(w.data.weather, function(i, res) {        
    contents += "<section>" + res.tempMaxC + "</section>";
});
```

All in all, you were pretty close. Here's [a working fiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/NmukX/) with the minor change.